# ECMAScript/JavaScript - inheritance and the new operator

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-5

I am currently learning to program JavaScript/ECMAScript, and I'm reading the book "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition". I'm enjoying the book, and at the same time I look for some support on the Internet with materials that describe the same subject. Like all OO programmers coming out from one language to learn another, I am having difficulties. I am currently in Chapter 6, studying about inheritance (PAG. 201, 202 - in case anyone have the book, and would like to see this part of it), and I am confused, getting unfocused.

I quite understand the mechanics behind the subject ... But I did not understand why. For example, the author of the book shows the following case (some lines were slightly adjusted with comments and separation):

```
// SUPERTYPE
function SuperType()
{
    this.property = true;
}

SuperType.prototype.getSuperValue = function()
{
    return this.property;
};

// SUBTYPE
function SubType()
{
    this.subproperty = false;
}

SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

SubType.prototype.getSubValue = function ()
{
    return this.subproperty;
};

// TEST
var instance = new SubType();
alert(instance.getSuperValue());    //true
```

I understand that in ECMAScript, instances of a type inherit properties and methods configured on its prototype, and it is through prototype property that inheritance is possible. Therefore, changing the prototype of one type to another type will cause behaviors and attributes to be reused.

What's driving me headless, is the fact assign a new instance of a type A as a prototype of a type B, where it is understood that B may have instances, as well as A too (not that this should happen, but it is **allowed** to happen).

What I mean by that? Well ... Imagine that I have a supertype named "Vehicle" and a subtype named "Car". If I use an instance of "Vehicle" to serve as supertype of "Car" (after all, a subtype does not know his supertype, but only its prototype - as PAG. 185 from the book says), I'm creating something totally abstract to serve as something concrete. Also, I'm using what is just one of perhaps many possible instances of a abstract supertype (?), since nothing prevents the supertype in future to have more instances of itself in this type of code, adding more code/methods/properties/etc.

**My real question is ... This is it anyway? Kind ... Developers should worry about associating the correct instance, and only one of them?**

Also, I have some doubts about the **prototype chain**. For example, I know that when a property/method is requested/used, it is first sought in the object, and then its prototype (if its not found). What happens visibly to the contexts in this story? I mean, the search is made only in the prototype chain of objects without running any context? I read earlier that when a variable is used, it is sought in stack of contexts. **What is the relationship between the stack of contexts and the prototype chain?**

I know I may be being a little boring/annoying to ask this, but can anyone explain me this in a simple and detailed way, please?

Thank you in advance for your patience, time, and attention.

### EDIT

As some people are really not understanding what I'm wondering, I apologize. Here is the summary of all:

Create new instances of A, where A is supertype of B, is something allowed and possible, even if A follows certain abstraction? And if this is allowed, what are its consequences? And where is the stack of contexts in between when something (property or method) is used by instances?

To summarize more: Although I am asking questions, realize that I am asking the implications of inheritance. Just that...

Comment: Try to narrow this down in to a few seperate questions. :)

Comment: Above comments, and dont use instances as prototypes!

Comment: I wanted to show the points that I have doubts. I have not done several questions. I only ask you to see the context of my post, if possible. Some people here in the community have the bad habit of looking out (jumping) for the question mark (the "?" sign). It is not the first time I ask this: Read the question and its context...

Comment: Its unclear to me what exactly you're asking here...

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, you want to know why `instance.getSuperValue()` is returning `SuperType`s  `this.subproperty` instead of `SubType`s?

Comment: `SubType.prototype = new SuperType()` is bad form. Do `SubType.prototype = Object.create(SuperType.prototype);` and if it's necessary to run the `SuperType` constructor, do it in the `SubType` constructor, i.e. `SuperType.call(this);`

Comment: Check out Codementor if you don't find what you're looking for here https://www.codementor.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JavaScript* has two big concepts that you seem to be touching on here, *Closure/Scope* and *Prototyping/inheritance*. These work differently most other modern languages so can cause confusion for people crossing over to *JavaScript* from a more classical language.

### Prototypes

Basically everything in *JavaScript* is an *Object*. In *JavaScript*, *Objects* have something called a *prototype* which is a reference to a parent *Object* which may have properties inherited by the descendant *Objects*. The *prototype* may also be `null`, which happens at the top end of the *prototype chain*.

The usual structure in prototypes is to have more specific objects inherit from more abstract objects, all the way back up to `Object.prototype` or `null`

When looking up a property on an object, you start from that object and if it doesn't have the property, you go up one level in the prototype chain and look again. If you reach `null` then there is no such property.
This also means you can shadow inherited properties by having properties of the same name lower down the prototype chain.

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {};
Foo.prototype.foobar = 'foo';

function Bar() {
    // if required
    // Foo.call(this);
}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype); // inhert
Bar.prototype.foobar = 'bar';

var baz = new Bar();
baz.foobar; // "bar"
baz instanceof Bar; // true
baz instanceof Foo; // true
```

A prototype can be any object, so there is nothing illegal about using an instance of another object to set up a prototype chain, however it's often considered bad practice if you're trying to extend or create a subtype

### Closure

This is how variables and identifiers are looked up. It's unrelated to the *prototype* and is entirely dependent on where something was defined. Identifiers are *"trapped"* inside a scope and other scopes can *"close over"* them.

In *JavaScript* the main providers of scope are *functions*

```
var a = 1;
function foo() {
    var b = 2;
    // foo can see `a` and `b` as well as `fizz`, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`
    function bar() {
        var c = 3;
        // bar can see `a`, `b` and `c` as well as `fizz`, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`
    }
    function baz() {
        var d = 4;
        // baz can see `a`, `b` and `d` as well as `fizz`, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`
    }
}
function fizz() {
    var e = 1;
    // fizz can see `a` and `e` as well as `fizz` and `foo`
}
```

However, if you were to create a property on `foo` that tried to lookup `bar`, you would get a *ReferenceError* (or *undefined*), similarly if you tried to inherit `foo`

```
foo.meth = function () {return bar;};
foo.meth(); // undefined

function Hello() {
    this.bar; // undefined
}
Hello.prototype = foo;
(new Hello()).bar; // undefined
```

The only way to access `bar` is to have `foo` do it for you, e.g. by `return bar;` at the end of `foo`

If `bar` was returned by `foo`, then the variables `foo` could see *"live on"* in `bar`. A smart garbage collector may still clean up unreachable ones if there is no eval-style code in `bar`.

Just as variables within a function are not shared across multiple invocations, these variables are not shared across multiple `foo` invocations, however they will be shared across multiple `bar` invocations

```
function foo() {
    var a = 0,
        b = -1;
    function bar() {
        return ++a;
    }
    return bar; // pass `bar` out of `foo`
}
var fn1 = foo(), fn2 = foo();
// by this point, the `b` created by `foo()` may already be cleaned up
fn1(); // 1
fn1(); // 2
fn2(); // 1, it's a different `a` to the `a` in `fn1`
fn2(); // 2
```

Comment: Your answer is very good, and explained me a few things. However, there were two things I did not understand.1 - Use Object.create() will cause two types have the same prototype, right? Would this not cause a behavior added to subtype to be also added for the supertype (with the prototype)? Also, would it not cause the subtype was the same type as the prototype, rather than its supertype?2- I do not quite understand the example you gave of closures, where you started with "However...". Why if I tried to create a property in "foo" I would not have access to "bar"? "bar" is a function of "foo".

Comment: Inside `foo` you can see `bar`, outside `foo` you cannot see `bar`. As for `Object.create()`, the first arg is the prototype, so it is saying "create a new object with the prototype of _Foo_ (`Foo.prototype`), and then set this new object as the prototype of _Bar_". It means properties added to `Bar.prototype` are not going on `Foo.prototype`, but an object that inherits `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: Try playing around with the examples I wrote; `(new Foo()).foobar; // "foo"`, `(new Bar()).foobar; // "bar"`